# How to call <p:ajax> from <p:commandLink> in JSF inside Editable Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have the following code

```
<p:ajax id="rowEditInit" event="rowEditInit"
   listener="#{assignIssueController.onEditInit}" />

<p:commandLink id="linkId" action="#{assignIssueController.initMethod}" >
    <p:rowEditor>
    </p:rowEditor>
</p:commandLink>
```

This is part of my editable datatable is there any way I can call my ajax event "rowEditInit" after commadlink is called?

Following is my Datatable

```
<h:form id="formId">
            <p:dataTable id="dTable" var="il"
                value="#{assignIssueController.issueList}" editable="true"
                style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <f:facet name="header">
           Assign Issues
                </f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                    listener="#{assignIssueController.onRowEdit}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                    listener="#{assignIssueController.onRowCancel}" />
                 <p:ajax id="rowEditInit" event="rowEditInit"
                    listener="#{assignIssueController.onEditInit}" />
                <p:column headerText="Issue Number">
                    <h:outputText value="#{il.issueNumber}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Issue Discribtion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{il.issueDescribtion}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Assign To">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{il.assignToUserId}" id="userId" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:autoComplete id="assignUserId" multiple="true"
                                value="#{assignIssueController.selectedUserList}"
                                completeMethod="#{assignIssueController.complete}" var="usr"
                                itemLabel="#{usr.userId}" itemValue="#{usr}"
                                converter="#{userConverter}">
                            </p:autoComplete>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Updated By">
                    <h:outputText value="#{il.updatedByUserId}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Issue Type">
                    <h:outputText value="#{il.issueStatus}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="display: none">
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{il.issueType}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:32px">
                <p:commandLink  id="linkId" action="#{assignIssueController.initMethod}">
                    <p:rowEditor>
                    </p:rowEditor>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

And here are the methods that are called by ajax events

```
public void onEditInit(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getObject());
        AssignIssueList obj = (AssignIssueList) event.getObject();
        issueName = obj.getIssueNumber();
        System.out.println(obj.getAssignToUserId().toString());
        selectedUserList = usersBo.getUserNameList(obj.getAssignToUserId().toString());
    }

    public void initMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
```

Comment: A row editor in a commandLink? Never seen that. PrimeFaces showcase shows a different usage. What is the non-technical usecase that you try to solve?

Comment: I have a editable datatable and in that one of the column is autocomplete. whenever i try to edit the row by clicking on the pencil icon i am loosing my old values of autocomplete.

Comment: The way you describe it, you have a autocomplete as the 'output' in the editable datatable. That is weird... but to prevent me making assumptions, you better ask a good question about that problem... This one (or at least what you are trying to do) I've never seen before and so uncommon that it most likely is the wrong way to 'solve' the original problem (See http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @David: Can you share the code code relevant to `p:autoComplete` and your pencil icon action?

Comment: @Parkash Kumar I have updated the question.